# grails urlMappings dsl

Tags: java, grails, groovy, dsl

I am trying to understand what happens behind the scenes of a grails url mapping call for example:

```
"/pages/admin"(controller:"admin", action:"admin")
```

Since this is valid **groovy** syntax, how does the above translate to **java code**?

Comment: Since Grails is built on Spring, I would assume that what is described in [1] and [2] might help.


  [1]: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-18207.html
  [2]: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html

Comment: Grails is built on Groovy. Spring is used in Grails, but has nothing to do with this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect methodMissing() is somehow involved. I just don't know if "/pages/admin" is considered a method name, or it is a string and methodMissing() is mixed-in into String class. In both cases though controller and action would be passed to methodMissing() as the second argument, parameters. The rest is easy.